# Adding headers to columns of admin app page in Django

Tags: django

I'm customizing the admin panel for my django app and saw that someone pre-1.8 was using list_display = ['join', 'email', 'timestamp', 'updated'] to add a header to the columns of his django app page and separated sections based on his model.

[image]

I've tried list_display in django 1.8 and I am failing to see any header names being posted. Is there a new command for this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Join


class JoinAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('emails', 'timestamp')
    class Meta:
        model = Join

admin.site.register(Join, JoinAdmin)
```

Issue needed to throw in second parameter in the admin.site.register of JoinAdmin